# Is the ruby Enumerable.Inject method a closure or just a block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, closures, dynamic-programming

I have been trying to understand if you need to create a proc or lambda before something is a closure in Ruby or not.

As a canonical example we can look at the inject method. It's using the yield keyword but is it a closure or just a block?

```
def inject(init)
  result = init
  each do |item|
    result = yield(result, item)
  end
  result
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A piece of code is a closure if it captures the enclosing scope, which a block does, so blocks (as well as lambdas and procs) are closures.

Methods defined using `def` however, don't close over anything, so `inject` is not a closure.

Comment: I've heard that a lamdda is not necessarily a closure. I'll see if I can find the reference to that. So inject isn't a closure but it accepts one?

Comment: @John: "I've heard that a lambda is not necessarily a closure." Whoever told you that might have meant that a block, lambda or proc is not a closure if it does not actually use any variables from the enclosing scope. However it should be pointed out, that even if the block does not use any variables from the enclosing scope, it still has a reference to them, so it's not necessarily meaningful to make such a distinction. "So inject isn't a closure but it accepts one." Yes, exactly.